# How can the objects of a certain subtype be obtained from an arraylist of superclass type?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I have 3 classes.

1. Animal (superclass)
2. Dog (subclass that extends Animal)
3. Cat (subclass that extends Animal)

I have an ArrayList that contains every Animal, whether it is a Dog or a Cat.
Is there a way to obtain only the Dog objects from the ArrayList?

Comment: You can iterate over the list and use the `instanceof` keyword to check if the current object is of the desired type (`Dog` for example).

Comment: Wouldn't that require me to cast? Is it a safe way or is it prone to errors?

Comment: You don't have to cast, unless you need to use specific methods that belong to the sub-type and not the super-type. For example, let's say `Dog` has the `bark()` method which is not defined in `Animal` and you need to call it, then in this case you have to cast the object. If you want to make it safe, then after you check with `instanceof`, you can cast without worrying about it.

Comment: You could do something like: `animals.stream().filter(animal->(animal instanceof Dog)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: As mention in the comments by @SomeDude and in the answer, you can use Java8 Streams and obtain the list of `Dog` objects. In this case you don't have to manually cast the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
List<Dog>  dogs = animals.stream().filter(animal -> animal instanceof Dog).map(dog-> Dog.class.cast(dog)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This seems to give a type mismatch and says that it cannot convert from List<Animal> to List<Dog>.

Comment: I have fixed it now, forgot to cast it to dog class

Answer (score 0):

First we `filter` instances of class `Dog`, then safely `map` into `Dog` and finally `collect` into a `List`:

```
List<Dog> dogs = animals.stream()
        .filter(Dog::isInstance)
        .map(Dog::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```